# Native code of eval() function in V8

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, native

I need to find the native code of the eval () function to register its call in debug (including logging the contents of the parameters passed to eval ()) in the V8 engine. But I can not do it. Can anybody help with this? And is it realistic to do this (registration of a call, viewing of parameters)?

Comment: Why do you need to find the native code? Just use monkey patching.

Comment: https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=f:v8+case:yes+GlobalEval&type=cs

Comment: What exactly are you trying to debug?

Comment: I want to create a [PIN](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) tool to instrumentize Chrome. Specifically, I want to create an application that allows to dynamically track the calls of certain functions (eval () for example) in the js script, and also view the contents of the function parameters with the possibility of changing

Comment: Looking at this kind of thing myself. Are you wanting to trace use of eval? Did you find anything in particular? I was thinking of going down the route of modifying the eval (abd any other functions I need to hook) code in V8...